# jquery .focus() function not working in windows chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I have the following jquery code snippet that isn't working in chrome windows, but is working fine in my macbook's chrome. Could not find any leads on searching.

```
$(function() {     
    var prev;
    $("#id_employment_status").focus(function() {
        prev = this.value;
        console.log("prev = " + prev)
    }).change(function()      {
        if (prev == 4) {
            //do something
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: The best thing to help in this situation is demonstrate an example of this problem with jsfiddle. We can investigate from there.

Comment: try putting code in document ready function and then try.

Comment: Did my code below helped?

Answer (score 0):

I think the following code should help you:

```
$(function() {
    var prev,
    $node =  $("#id_employment_status");

    // setup on focus and change event handlers
    $node.focusin(function() {
        prev = this.value;
    })
    .change(function(){
        if (prev == 4) {
            //do something
        }
    });

    // then fire the focus
    // if this fails try calling after 0~10ms delay
    $node.focus();
});
```

Good luck, have fun!

Comment: I used a .click() event instead, and it worked. Didn't try your solution though. Can you explain the logic behind your code working in windows and mine not?